# SQL Query to show hour before current time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL DB with date time format as follow

0000-00-00 00:00:00

I want to run a SQL query to show me any information older than one hour but not older than 4 hours from the current time

```
SELECT * FROM gs_objects WHERE dt_server < NOW()
```

This currently shows me all information older than current time, how can I change that to give me information older than one hour but not older than 4 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_sub` to find the datetime range:

```
select *
from gs_objects
where dt_server between date_sub(now(), interval 4 hour)
                and date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
```

if you don't want the rows with datetime exactly 4 hours before, you can use:

```
select *
from gs_objects
where dt_server > date_sub(now(), interval 4 hour)
and   dt_server <= date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
```

Comment: Thanks his worked for me, last question will this work if I want 30 mins as well and if I write min as 0.5 instead of 1 hour?

Comment: You don't need the function date_sub @TrevorAckermann in MySQL you can directly substract DATETIME formats with `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

Comment: "if I want 30 mins as well and if I write min as 0.5 instead of 1 hour?" @TrevorAckermann No you need to use `INTERVAL 30 MINUTE` instead

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this *should* get what you're chasing.

[Using DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to find the time 1 hour and 4 hours ago with the comparison.

```
where dt_server < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
  and dt_server > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR )
```